# Express with AngularJS - How to parse data directly into an html template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, templates, express

I have an Express / Angular app and I am trying to add a title via the app.get() method, rather than adding it via angular. Is there a way to do this without using a template engine?

My server.js file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

My route (using express.Router)

```
// Default load public index.html
publicRouter.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../public', 'index.html'));
});
```

I am pretty sure I am doing this wrong. I would like to do something like this:

```
publicRouter.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../public', 'index.html'), {
        title: "My Webpage",
    });
});
```

So that then in my index.html, I can render the title directly into the template:

```
<title>{{ title }}</title>
```

... without it being part of the route scope. This is because the title is rendered before angular is loaded, and if I load it in Angular, the tags show momentarily while angular loads. This isn't cool.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution to your problem.
Maybe try creating a custom directive for it.
Something like this

```
<title my-title=" 'title' "><\title>
```

Will be rendered to

```
<title ...>{{title}}<\title>
```

This way, the title tag will be empty as long as angular isn't loaded.

Comment: Could this make the title render before the rest of the html? My problem is that there is that split second the page loads, and the title is dynamically loaded via angular, which is loaded way after the title tag.

Comment: No, it doesn't make it render first, but it makes the wait look cleaner. I mean the `{{ .. }}` brackets won't be shown with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complex `index.html` is, and given your requirement of not using a server-side templating engine, you could use template literals (i.e., strings wrapped in backticks instead of quotes which lets you do multiline strings nicely; available in ES6 or TypeScript compiled to ES5) to interpolate your page title.

```
publicRouter.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
    res.send(getHtml('My webpage'));
});

publicRouter.get('/bar', function(req, res) {
    res.send(getHtml('My other webpage'));
});

function getHtml(title) {
    return `
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>${title}</title>
            </head>
            <body ng-app="myApp">
                <div ng-view></div>
                <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            </body>
        </html>
    `;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the index.html is far too complex for me to implement this cleanly.